# How do I change display settings like brightness, contrast, etc. on my notebook?

Tags: 12.10, display

I have a Samsung Series 9 notebook 15" ([model NP900X3C](http://www.samsung.com/ae/consumer/computers-peripherals/notebook/ultra-portable/NP900X3C-A01AE)) and I would like to adjust the screen settings (brightness, contrast, saturation, etc.).

If I go to *System Settings* → *Color*, I see my screen listed as a device, but I have to add a profile in order to 'calibrate'. I am clueless about how to do that.

Is this the right place to go? Is there another way to change the screen settings?

The graphics card is an Intel HD3000 integrated one and I'm running Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: @gertvdijk Intel HD 3000 Graphics. In All Settings > Details > graphics, I have : `Driver: unknown, Experience: Standard`

Answer (score 7):

Open in System Settings → Brightness and Lock

[image]

Otherwise, play with `xgamma`. For instance, type in terminal

```
 xgamma -gamma 1.3
```

Read the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/xgamma.1x.html) to see how to change only blue, red or green. Once you set the best gamma that fits your needs, you can write a bash script: create a file `xgamma.sh` in your /home directory. Paste the content of your gamma settings. For example:

```
#! /bin/bash
xgamma -gamma 1.3
```

Save it and make it executable. Finally add it to the Startup Applications.

[image]

Comment: nvidia application let us modify each color component (r,g,b) individually concerning: gamma, brightness and contrast; xgamma only let us modify gamma; I wonder if there is a command line tool for brigness and contrast too?