# How do I adjust the contrast.

Tags: laptop, display, hp-pavilion

Does anyone know how  to adjust the contrast on the Ubuntu Operating system? I have an HP Pavilion G6 Laptop, any help would be great!

Comment: Look at:
[http://askubuntu.com/questions/247251/how-do-i-change-display-settings-like-brightness-contrast-etc-on-my-notebook](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247251/how-do-i-change-display-settings-like-brightness-contrast-etc-on-my-notebook)